# ListView setting animation value of next item to 1.0 when previous item removed from list (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView.seperated that is displaying a list of widgets. They each contain their own animated object and each have their own AnimationController and Animation.

The problem is when I have one or more items in that list whose animation is finished e.g. their `animation.value` is `1.0`, and I remove those objects from the list then the following items animation values end up being `1.0`.

e.g.

If there are 3 items and I remove the first, the second item's animation.value become (1.0 i.e. completed).

If there are 5 items and I removed the first two, the third and fourth item's animations become completed.

This obviously isn't what I want or expect to happen :D

Below is a full working example of what I'm trying to do ... put it in your "main.dart" and you'll be ready to go

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Example(),
    );
  }
}

class ItemModel {
  final String id;
  final String title;

  ItemModel({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
  });
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  List<ItemModel> _items = [
    ItemModel(id: '1', title: 'A'),
    ItemModel(id: '2', title: 'B'),
    ItemModel(id: '3', title: 'C'),
    ItemModel(id: '4', title: 'D'),
  ];

  List<ItemModel> _selectedItems = [];

  void _addToSelected(ItemModel itemModel) {
    if (_selectedItems.contains(itemModel)) {
      _selectedItems.removeWhere((item) => item.id == itemModel.id);
    } else {
      _selectedItems.add(itemModel);
    }
    setState(() {});
    print('>>> selected items: $_selectedItems');
  }

  void _delete() async {
    await Future(() {
      _selectedItems.forEach((selectedItem) {
        _items.removeWhere((item) => item.id == selectedItem.id);
      });
    });
    _selectedItems.clear();
    setState(() {});
    print('>>> selected items: $_selectedItems');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          if (_selectedItems.length >= 1)
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Items: ${_selectedItems.length}'),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: _delete),
              ],
            )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: _items.length,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        separatorBuilder: (ctx, i) => Divider(),
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListItem(_items[i], _addToSelected),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final ItemModel itemModel;
  final Function addToSelected;

  const ListItem(this.itemModel, this.addToSelected);
  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  bool _isSelected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (_animationController != null) {
      _animationController.dispose();
      _animationController = null;
    }
  }

  void _animateSelect() {
    if (_isSelected) {
      _isSelected = false;
      _animationController.reverse();
      widget.addToSelected(widget.itemModel);
    } else {
      _isSelected = true;
      _animationController.forward();
      widget.addToSelected(widget.itemModel);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _selected() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    );
  }

  Widget _unselected() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    );
  }

  Widget _listItem() {
    return Transform(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
        ..rotateY(pi * _animation.value),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: _animateSelect,
        child: _animation.value <= 0.5 ? _unselected() : _selected(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _listItem();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of whether a listItem is selected or not in one place instead of multiple. Why not pass `_selectedItems` to the `ListItem` so it can see whether it is selected or not?

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Example(),
    );
  }
}

class ItemModel {
  final String id;
  final String title;

  ItemModel({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
  });
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  List<ItemModel> _items = [
    ItemModel(id: '1', title: 'A'),
    ItemModel(id: '2', title: 'B'),
    ItemModel(id: '3', title: 'C'),
    ItemModel(id: '4', title: 'D'),
  ];

  List<ItemModel> _selectedItems = [];

  void _addToSelected(ItemModel itemModel) {
    if (_selectedItems.contains(itemModel)) {
      _selectedItems.removeWhere((item) => item.id == itemModel.id);
    } else {
      _selectedItems.add(itemModel);
    }
    setState(() {});
    print('>>> selected items: $_selectedItems');
  }

  void _delete() async {
    await Future(() {
      _selectedItems.forEach((selectedItem) {
        _items.removeWhere((item) => item.id == selectedItem.id);
      });
    });
    _selectedItems.clear();
    setState(() {});
    print('>>> selected items: $_selectedItems');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          if (_selectedItems.length >= 1)
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Items: ${_selectedItems.length}'),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: _delete),
              ],
            )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: _items.length,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        separatorBuilder: (ctx, i) => Divider(),
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListItem(_items[i], _addToSelected, _selectedItems),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final ItemModel itemModel;
  final Function addToSelected;
  final List selectedItems;

  const ListItem(this.itemModel, this.addToSelected, this.selectedItems);
  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (_animationController != null) {
      _animationController.dispose();
      _animationController = null;
    }
  }

  void _animateSelect() {
    if (widget.selectedItems.contains(widget.itemModel)) {
      _animationController.reverse();
      widget.addToSelected(widget.itemModel);
    } else {
      print("forward");
      _animationController.reset();
      _animationController.forward();
      widget.addToSelected(widget.itemModel);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _selected() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    );
  }

  Widget _unselected() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    );
  }

  Widget _listItem() {
    return Transform(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
        ..rotateY(pi * _animation.value * 2),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: _animateSelect,
        child: widget.selectedItems.contains(widget.itemModel) ? _selected() : _unselected(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _listItem();
  }
}
```

Resetting `_animationController` before calling it to go forward seems to be nescessary here too.

Also, I changed `..rotateY(pi * _animation.value)` to `..rotateY(pi * _animation.value * 2)` otherwise whenever a card is selected it will be backwards, including any text on it. If that was your intent in the first place, then you can change that back.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. It was a good idea but I don't really want the animation to spin rotate twice and it was also displaying the alternate widget before the animation reached half way (by defining based on selected or not). I've kind of patched the problem by showing a loading spinner instead of the list view and then reverting once "deleting" has finished ... Wasn't what I wanted to do and I still can't understand why different widgets are inheriting the properties of others ..